# Invalid Syntax with my "if statement"

Tags: python, syntax

I have an issue with my if statement and I don't understand why. Here it is:

```
if (first == 1 and second > -1 and third < 1 and (sign(phi[i]) == sign(phi[i-1]) or sign(phi[i]) == sign(phi[i-2])):
foo()
```

It keeps telling me `"invalid syntax"`.
Can you spot the invalid syntax?

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, for starters. Second of all, what have you tried?

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis at the end or having one too many at the start. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Voting to close as typo/norepro

Answer (score 3):

You have missed one parenthesis at the end:

```
if (first == 1 and second > -1 and third < 1 and (sign(phi[i]) == sign(phi[i-1]) or sign(phi[i]) == sign(phi[i-2]))):
                                                                                                                   ^
```